# How do you prepopulate a Vue text field from Vuex state?

Tags: vue.js, input, vuex, auto-populate

I am trying to get a user's name to be prepopulated in the below text field.

```
<v-text-field
    v-model.trim="name"
>{{ currentName }}</v-text-field> 

data: () => ({
    name: '', 
  }),
  computed: {
    currentName() {
      return this.$store.state.name
    },
  }
```

I feel like I am missing something very simple, but I have tried so many variations that  I am completely stumped. Please and Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to hydrate the `name` property with `this.$store.state.name`

Comment: Use getters and setters for the `name` computed prop. Getter will return the store state, while the setter should probably dispatch an action or commit a mutation in your VueX store that updates the store state. Also based your comment it seems like you have not configured the VueX store yet.

Answer (score 0):

@Terry you got it! Thanks!

```
<v-text-field
  v-model.trim="getName">{{ getName }}</v-text-field>

data: () => ({ name: '' })

computed: {
    getName: {
      get: function() {
        return this.$store.state.name
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.name = newValue
      }
    }

methods: {
    submit() {
      if(!this.name) {
        this.name = this.$store.state.name
      } 
      this.$store.dispatch('updateMe', {
        name: this.name,
      });
    }

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    name: null,
  }
```